# how to insert frame in word document using poi or any other API

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

How to insert a frame into word file from my Java code using Apache POI?

I want frame(with left border only) to insert at top-right of the page.

You can see the frame highlighted in red box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use docx4j. It is easier to deal with docx files with docx4j.
You can look at: http://blog.iprofs.nl/2012/10/22/adding-images-and-layout-to-your-docx4j-generated-word-documents-part-1/

Here is the code :

```
public class AddingAnInlineImage {
/**
 *  As is usual, we create a package to contain the document.
 *  Then we create a file that contains the image we want to add to the document.
 *  In order to be able to do something with this image, we'll have to convert
 *  it to an array of bytes. Finally we add the image to the package
 *  and save the package.
 */
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    WordprocessingMLPackage  wordMLPackage =
        WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

    File file = new File("src/main/resources/iProfsLogo.png");
    byte[] bytes = convertImageToByteArray(file);
    addImageToPackage(wordMLPackage, bytes);

    wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("src/main/files/HelloWord7.docx"));
}

/**
 *  Docx4j contains a utility method to create an image part from an array of
 *  bytes and then adds it to the given package. In order to be able to add this
 *  image to a paragraph, we have to convert it into an inline object. For this
 *  there is also a method, which takes a filename hint, an alt-text, two ids
 *  and an indication on whether it should be embedded or linked to.
 *  One id is for the drawing object non-visual properties of the document, and
 *  the second id is for the non visual drawing properties of the picture itself.
 *  Finally we add this inline object to the paragraph and the paragraph to the
 *  main document of the package.
 *
 *  @param wordMLPackage The package we want to add the image to
 *  @param bytes         The bytes of the image
 *  @throws Exception    Sadly the createImageInline method throws an Exception
 *                       (and not a more specific exception type)
 */
private static void addImageToPackage(WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage,
                        byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart =
        BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(wordMLPackage, bytes);

    int docPrId = 1;
    int cNvPrId = 2;
        Inline inline = imagePart.createImageInline("Filename hint",
            "Alternative text", docPrId, cNvPrId, false);

    P paragraph = addInlineImageToParagraph(inline);

    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(paragraph);
}

/**
 *  We create an object factory and use it to create a paragraph and a run.
 *  Then we add the run to the paragraph. Next we create a drawing and
 *  add it to the run. Finally we add the inline object to the drawing and
 *  return the paragraph.
 *
 * @param   inline The inline object containing the image.
 * @return  the paragraph containing the image
 */
private static P addInlineImageToParagraph(Inline inline) {
    // Now add the in-line image to a paragraph
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    P paragraph = factory.createP();
    R run = factory.createR();
    paragraph.getContent().add(run);
    Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();
    run.getContent().add(drawing);
    drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);
    return paragraph;
}

/**
 * Convert the image from the file into an array of bytes.
 *
 * @param file  the image file to be converted
 * @return      the byte array containing the bytes from the image
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static byte[] convertImageToByteArray(File file)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file );
    long length = file.length();
    // You cannot create an array using a long, it needs to be an int.
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.println("File too large!!");
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }
    // Ensure all the bytes have been read
    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        System.out.println("Could not completely read file "
                    +file.getName());
    }
    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```